# How to get all database name present in a mongodb server in laravel

Tags: mongodb, laravel, mongodb-query

I'm using [jenssegers mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) library for mongodb database interaction in laravel. I'm not able to find an API to get list of all databases names resides in a server either in laravel doc or in [jenssegers mongodb](https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb).

For example, following all the databases present in my mongodb server

```
college_1
college_2
college_3
```

I want to get the list of databases.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty late answer but you can do it with :

- With Jessengers (https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/blob/master/src/Jenssegers/Mongodb/Connection.php)

  `DB::connection('<yourconnection>')->getMongoClient()->listDatabases()`
- With MongoDB/Client (https://docs.mongodb.com/php-library/v1.2/reference/method/MongoDBClient__construct/)

  `$client = new Client($uri);`

  `$client->listDatabases();`

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned library requires a php sdk of mongodb, inside it there is a [function](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-library/blob/master/src/Client.php#L219) to list the databases:

I read through the documentation, and I believe, you can get this to work is by: (i didn't test)

`DB::connection('mongodb')->getMongoDB()->listDatabases()`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the tested solution,

```
$data = DB::connection('mongodb')->getMongoClient()->listDatabases();
dd($data);
```